# How to not separate on dash/hyphen when using lodash _.words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, lodash, words

I am using lodash to split up usernames that are fed to me in a string with some sort of arbitrary separator. I would like to use _.words() to split strings up into words, except for hyphens, as some of the user names contain hyphens.

Example:

```
_.words(['user1,user2,user3-adm'], RegExp)
```

I want it to yield:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3-adm']
```

not this (_.words(array) without any pattern):

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'adm']
```

What is the right String/RegExp to use to make this happen?

Comment: Are you using any pattern for RegExp matching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initial case can be solved by this:

```
_.words(['user1,user2,user3-adm'], /[^,]+/g);
```

Result:

```
["user1", "user2", "user3-adm"]
```

---

**[EDITED]**

If you want to add more separators, add like this:

```
_.words(['user1,user2,user3-adm.user4;user5 user7'], /[^,.\s;]+/g);
```

Result:

```
["user1", "user2", "user3-adm", "user4", "user5", "user7"]
```

Last snippet will separate by:

commas (`,`), 
dots (`.`), 
spaces (`\s`), 
semicolons (`;`)

---

Alternatively you can use:

```
 _.words(['user1,user2,user3-adm.user4;user5 user7*user8'], /[-\w]+/g)
```

Result:

```
 ["user1", "user2", "user3-adm", "user4", "user5", "user7", "user8"]
```

In this case you can add what you **don't want** as delimiter. Here it will will be separated by every character which is not `\w` (same as `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`) or `-`(dash)

Comment: Is there a way to say "use all recognized separators except for dashes?"

Comment: You need to say what you want to use as separator or don't. Maybe what I included to my answer can help you.

Answer (score 5):

`words` accept a regex expression to match the words and **not to split** them, being so, just use a regex that matches everything besides a comma, i.e.:

```
_.words(['user1,user2,user3-adm'], /[^,]+/g);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `split`.

```
result = wordlist.split(/,/);
```

---

https://lodash.com/docs#words

Comment: It's a little more complex than that since users can use commas, dots, spaces, or other punctuation as separators. I only want to pick dashes to ignore.

Comment: "__users can use commas, dots, spaces, or other punctuation as separators__" I couldn't read that on your question.